# Sort images by aspect ratio then use MPV to browse

Tags: shell, awk, sed, sort

I want to sort images by aspect ratio, then use [MPV](https://mpv.io) to browse them, and I got some codes from Google:

```
identify * | gawk '{split($3,sizes,"x"); print $1,sizes[1]/sizes[2]}' | sed 's/\[.\]//' | sort -gk 2
```

This is a output:

```
28.webp 0.698404
1.webp 0.699544
27.webp 0.706956
10.webp 0.707061
25.webp 0.707061
9.webp 0.707061
2.webp 0.707241
22.webp 1.41431
23.webp 1.41431
24.webp 1.41431
```

Then I made some adaptations to fit my need:

```
identify * | gawk '{split($3,sizes,"x"); print $1,sizes[1]/sizes[2]}' | sed 's/\[.\]//' | sort -gk 2 | gawk '{print $1}' | mpv --no-resume-playback --really-quiet --playlist=-
```

It works, but isn't perfect. It can't deal with filename with space and `identify` is too slower than `exiftool` especially when handling WebP format, besides, `exiftool` has a `-r` option, so I want to use `exiftool` to get this output instead, but I don't know how to deal with the output of `exiftool -r -s -ImageSize`, anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `mpv`, but in the `zsh` shell, to order a list of files based on some criteria like the aspect ratio, you can use the `o+function` glob qualifier to order a glob expansion based on information returned by a `function`.

So for instance:

```
by_aspect_ratio() REPLY=$(
  exiftool -q -if 'printf "%d", $ImageWidth*1e8/$ImageHeight;0' -- $REPLY
)

print -rC1 -- *.webp(no+by_aspect_ratio)
```

would `print` a list of `webp` files (`r`aw on `1` `C`olumn) sorted by aspect ratio.

You'd likely want to use:

```
your-image-viewer -- *.webp(no+by_aspect_ratio)
```

to pass that sorted list of files to your favourite image viewer.

Replace `*.webp` with `**/*.webp` to look for `webp` files recursively.

Or with any shell but assuming GNU utilities, and using `exiftool`'s `-r` as per the latest edit of your question:

```
exiftool -r -ext webp -q -if '
  printf "%g\t%s\0", $ImageWidth/$ImageHeight, "$directory/$filename";0' . |
  sort -zn |
  cut -zf2- |
  xargs -r0 your-image-viewer
```